# Error: Could not find or load main class in Android Project

Tags: android, project

I am trying to run a program for an Android Project and getting an error that reads "Error: Could not find or load main class myPackage.myClass"

This package and class no longer exist in my project. I added them temporarily in it's own package, then deleted them, and now I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Some how when the other class was inserted into the project the run configuration was looking for main (which is what is supposed to happen in a Java project - not an Android project) when it should have been looking for MainActivity, which calls onCreate() when it first starts (as opposed to main).

What I did to fix this is I clicked the dropdown arrow on the "Run" button >> Lanch Configuration, then in the left hand side menu Android Application >> , then make sure radio button "launch default activity" is selected and click run. Eclipse will then start to launch the project in the AndroidVD as normal.

I think this will be useful to other Android noobs out there that are trying crazy things with their projects.